# fullpage.js plugin not working net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: amazon-web-services, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js plug in for a website I am building as it allows me to display each page as a slide which locks in on scroll. Here is the website if you are interested in taking a look: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Locally it loads fine and the page works and looks exactly how I would like it too, however, once I upload my files to amazon AWS I get a whole list of console errors but the root seems to be that the fullpage.js files are forbidden. I have tried using a CDN to pull the files, however, this has not been successful. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I did not set the right permissions in AWS for the folder containing the files, I moved the files into the root folder and it works.